# Static selected option in <select> disappears after dynamically rendering other <options>

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<select formControlName="disponibilidad" [ngClass]="invalidDisponibilidadClass">
      <option value="null" disabled="true" [selected]="true" style="font-weight: bold;">Disponibilidad</option>
      <option *ngFor="let option of disponibilidadOptions "[value]="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

"disponibilidadOptions" variable is the result of an http call. As soon as the variable has values, it renders the options dynamically and the select appears empty.
The behaviour I'm looking for is for the static option to remain selected.

Comment: try to push the static value in disponibilidadOptions  in the .ts file and remove it from html file

Answer (score 0):

The issue will occur when your `disponibilidad` FormControl has non-null value.

If you haven't set any value for it, and have only initialized it, then try to initialize it with `null` value as:

```ts
this.someForm = new FormGroup({
  // other controls
  disponibilidad: new FormControl(null)
});

// If using FormBuilder
this.someForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  // other controls
  disponibilidad: [null],
});
```

In case if the above solution doesn't work, please do share the `ts` file showing the form group initialization code.